# How to make files as dowloadable links in PHP?

Tags: php, file, download

I am listing the files from a directory with scandir function and displaying the names in a table row . My question is how to make the listed files downloadable links and how to remove the first two rows which aren't file names which are '.' and '..' ?

Here is my code:

```
$result = scandir('test');

<table border = "1">
            <?php

            foreach($result as $value){

                echo "<tr>
                        <td>$value</td>
                      </tr>";

            }

            ?>

</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "downloadable", as opposed to links that aren't?

Comment: it's html. how do you make links in html?

Comment: links are made by <a> tag but how to make them downloadable , when you click then the file to start downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code to

```
$result = scandir('test');

<table border = "1">
            <?php

            foreach($result as $value){
            if($value == "." OR $value == ".."){continue;}
                echo "<tr>
                        <td><a href='download.php?value=".$value."'>".$value."</a></td>
                      </tr>";

            }

            ?>

</table>
```

Create file download.php and put inside it the following code:

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_GET['value']);
finfo_close($finfo);
$size = filesize($_GET['value']);
header("Content-Type: ". $mime);
header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $_GET['value']);
echo file_get_contents($_GET['value']);
?>
```

This will allow you to automatically download *every* type of file, including, for example .html.
If you're looking for something to download files that browser can't understand, answer of @maskacovnik  is the one that suits most to this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force the download you should try this code:

```
<?php
$dir = "test";
$result = scandir($dir);
?>
<table border = "1">
            <?php

            foreach($result as $value){

                if(strlen(str_replace('.','',$value)) > 0)
                {
                    echo '<tr>
                            <td><a target="_blank" href="download.php?file='.base64_encode($dir."/".$value).'">'.$value.'</a></td>
                          </tr>';
                }
            }

            ?>

</table>
```

Create also a `download.php` file where you paste the force-download code below:

```
<?php
    $file_url = base64_decode($_GET['file']);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
    readfile($file_url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = scandir('test');

<table border = "1">
            <?php
            foreach($result as $value){
                if($value == ".." || $value == ".") continue;
                echo '<tr><td><a href="test\\'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a></td></tr>';
            }
            ?>
</table>
```